# How set width of TextView same as height and redraw it?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have notesCounter(TextView) in expandableListView, in header row. I want to draw equal circle. TextView height is set match_parent. Now begin my problem... I want to set width of oval same as height. I measure it, it return me correct value (height), I set it to TextView, but it doesn't refresh. My question: how to refresh TextView?

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View rowView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Container container = (Container) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (rowView == null) {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_container, null);
    }
    TextView containerName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.container_name);
    containerName.setText(container.name);

    notesCounter = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.notes_counter);
    notesCounter.setText(getChildrenCount(groupPosition) + "");

    final TextView nt = notesCounter;
    notesCounter.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // nt.getHeight() - return 67 - good!
            notesCounter.setWidth(nt.getHeight()); // I WANT REDRAW IT AND SEE EQUAL CIRCLE! 
            //notesCounter will set width after swipe ExpandableListView and "hide and then appear view"
        }
    });

    Util.loadFont(context, containerName, FONT.GothamExtraLight);
    Util.loadFont(context, notesCounter, FONT.GothamExtraLight);

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: Hi there you can call invalidate() on TextView

Comment: It doesn't works for me.

Comment: How about `notesCounter.requestLayout()` ?

Answer (score 0):

See here below:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            notesCounter.setWidth(notesCounter.getHeight());
        }
    });
```

Comment: It still work same like my code. Third header drawing well, but first and second header draw wrongly. It's because post Runnable measure height AFTER draw first and second header. I need to refresh them, but how?